# Where do I get end-game gear for Warlords of Draenor?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

After reaching level 100, I picked up gear with item-level >= 620 from around Draenor.  I also got some from LFR and heroic dungeons.  But now I don't know what to do.  I've heard you can get even better gear:

- Doing harder raids *(How?  I don't see a difficulty-option in raid-finder)*
- "World bosses" *(who and where are they?)*
- Buying with various currencies *(How do I get them?  Who do I buy from?)*

But I don't know how to do those.  And is there anyplace else to get better gear?

*(I've seen [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65505/how-to-get-better-gear-as-a-high-level-character) which appears to be the same question by the title; but it's actually asking what stats to prioritize)*

Comment: FWIW, [this Wowhead guide](http://www.wowhead.com/guide=2688/gearing-up-in-warlords-of-draenor) may help.

Comment: Raid finder is it's own difficulty. You need a guild. Lone Wolfs won't get far in any MMORPG

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Getting gear became a lot harder for casual and unexperienced players with the release of Warlords of Draenor. If you say you want better gear I assume you mean Items above level 630/636 which can be obtained in Heroic Dungeons.

Everything at item level 640 and above is considered Epic gear (with the exception of crafted weapons. Those are 630).

Here are the options you have to access this gear and the difficulty.

### Item Level 640

- **Crafted Items**. While these are easy to obtain, they might be quite expensive. Especially upgrading them. These Items are also technically the best of this Item level since you can reroll the stats on it (getting your BiS stats).
- **Looking for Raid**. Without a doubt the easiest and most cost efficient way of obtaining items at this Item level.
- **Challenge Mode Dailys**. This one is a bit tricky. It can also reward you with BiS gear but you can only do the daily once per day and the Challenge modes aren't as easy as the other methods listed here.

### Item Level 645

- **Garrison Missions**. Once your followers are upgraded to a item level of 630 you will start getting missions  that reward you with Epic gear. The frequency of these missions is RNG.

### Item Level 650

- **World Bosses**. Drov and Tarlna can both drop 650 gear once per week.

### Item Level 655

- **Highmaul Normal**. The normal difficulty of Highmaul provides you with 655 gear. Normal mode is quite easy and you can usually finish the raid with random groups within 2 hours while the endboss is the biggest problem. Use the group finder tool to join a group or have an eye on the trade chat.
- **Highmaul Missions**. With a follower item level of 645 you will unlock the highmaul missions. These have a cooldown of two weeks and they can contain anything from the loot table of highmaul.
- **Crafted Items**. Upgrading a crafted Item will boost it's item Level to 655. This is usually really expensive (about 15-30k gold depending on your server) but will again be your BiS gear for this Item level since you can reroll the stats.

### Item Level 660

- **Conquest Point Gear**. You can buy gear with conquest points from PvP vendors. The gear is actually really nice for PvE and it's BiS for PvP. If you play your arena cap you'll have a free item every 1-2 weeks.

### Item Level 665

- **BoE World Drops**. Sometimes you are lucky and you'll find a BoE world drop. These are really rare but they can drop from pretty much every NPC (and from your lvl 3 salvage yard).

### Item Level 670

- **Highmaul Heroic**. Same as Highmaul Normal, this will be your best and fastest way of getting Items at this item level. The raid is a little bit harder but it's still easily managable although a lot of pugs will struggle after Butcher.
- **Highmaul Missions**. Works exactly the same as normal Highmaul missions. You'll unlock these after defeating 15 Highmaul Bosses on Normal difficulty.
- **Crafted Items**. The last upgrade of the items will boost the item level to 670. Again this is your BiS gear if rerolled correctly.

### Item Level 685

- **Highmaul Mythic**. Now this one is a bit harder. The first boss is puggable but after that you will face some trouble with random groups. If you want to gear up with item level 685 this Mythic Highmaul is your best way to go but you'll usually need an experienced raid group.
- **Highmaul Missions**. Same as Normal and Heroic HM missions. You'll unlock these after defeating 15 Bosses on Heroic Difficulty. This is the easiest way to get this gear but it only works once every two weeks.

### Item Level 695

- **Black market auction house**. Until the release of Blackrock Foundry the BMAH is your only way of obtaining this Item level. Expect to pay a lot of money for one of these items. And by a lot I mean somewhere between 100,000 - 900,000 gold.

Comment: The HighMaul ilvl 685 missions require you to defeat 15Hc bosses. Not defeat Mar'gok on hc difficulty

Comment: Apexis Crystals can be used as well, see Lyrion's answer.

Comment: Few notes: You can only use 3 crafted items at a time. Upgrading crafted items is significantly easier with a level 3 barn. The quickest way of increasing the ilvl of your followers is to get a War Mill and Salvage Yard, both can provide armor and weapon enhancements. The War Mill at level 3 will also give you one re-roll token per week (this is best used on the World Bosses if you are not running anything other than LFR). You can also obtain more of these tokens from a vendor in Ashran (max of 3 per week I believe), you can purchase these for honor, Apexis Shards, money or garrison resources.

Comment: Could you update this for BRF?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Unfortunately I stopped playing shortly after the release of BRF and thus I've also stopped informing myself about the game. But I can make the post Community Wiki if anyone wants to add something :)

Answer (score 3):

For doing harder raids from Normal to Mythic you will be either stuck doing PuG's or joining a guild. The raid-finder can only give you the LFR difficulty which drops iLvl640.

At the moment of writing there are 2 world bosses both in Gogrond:

- [Tarlna the Ageless](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=81535)
- [Drov the Ruiner](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=81252)

But when the Black Rock Foundry is released a third can be found at Spire's of arak:

- [Rukhmar](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=87493)

As for currency there are at the moment 2 ways to gain upgrades:

- [Conquest points](http://www.wowhead.com/currency=390/conquest-points) : These you get for doing arena, you will also get 50 for winning a BG, doing Ashran or from a gladiator's sanctum in your garrison. With conquest points you can buy primal gladiator gear that has an iLvl of 660.
- [Apexis Crystal's](http://www.wowhead.com/currency=823/apexis-crystal) : These you get from completing your daily quest in your garrison, from doing your daily inn quests, you can get them from work orders in your garrison aswell. And some quests also give them as reward. These will let you buy iLvl 630 gear, but you can upgrade them 2 times, each upgrade costing more crystals. The first upgrade is to iLvl 645 and the second upgrade is iLvl655

Answer (score 3):

To get better gear than item level 620 you can

- do Heroic Dungeons in the Group Finder tool (default hotkey <kbd>I</kbd>), these award item level 630 gear.
- do LFR raids in the Group Finder Tool, these award item level 640 gear for Highmaul LFR and item level 650 gear for Blackrock Foundry LFR (Blackrock Foundry will be available in february, see [here](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/blog/17541534/blackrock-foundry-raid-schedule-1-14-2015)).
- do raids in Normal difficulty, these award item level 655 ([Highmaul](http://www.wowhead.com/zone=6996)) and 665 ([Blackrock Foundry](http://www.wowhead.com/zone=6967)). To find groups for this raid difficulty use the trade chat on your realm or the Group Finder tool under "Premade Groups" - "Raids - Warlords of Draenor".
- Later you can also do Heroic difficulty the same way like Normal but the groups often require a higher item level and experience in Normal difficulty. These raids reward item level 670 (Highmaul) and 680 (Blackrock Foundry).
- do the world bosses ([Drov](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=81252) and [Tarlna](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=81535)). Both are located in the Gorgrond zone and show often up on the map for this zone. They drop item level 650 gear but you can only get loot from one boss per week. You can find groups for these in trade chat or the Group Finder tool under "Premade Groups" - "Custom". A third world boss ([Rukhmar](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=87493)) will be added in february (see the link above for Blackrock Foundry) and will drop item level 665 gear.
- buy gear in your Ashran capital city for [Apexis Crystals](http://www.wowhead.com/currency=823). This gear starts with item level 630 and can be upgraded (for even more crystals) to item level 645 and 655. (The vendors for the first stage: [Horde](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=86378) / [Alliance](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=86389)). You get Apexis Crystals from a daily quest in your garrison main building.
- buy PVP gear with [Conquest Points](http://www.wowhead.com/currency=390). This gear has item level 660 and is sold in Ashran, vendors: [Horde](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=88569) / [Alliance](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=86176).
- craft your own gear with professions or buy it from other players (over trade chat or auction house). This gear starts with item level 640 (630 for weapons and shields) and can be upgraded further to item level 655 and 670 (645 and 660) with other profession items which require [Savage Blood](http://www.wowhead.com/item=118472). The initial items cost only a ew thousand gold (depending on the realm).
- find or buy rare epic world drops with item level 655. These can drop from every level 100 and above mob, but are very rare. You may find some in the auction house.

PS: You find more information about dungeons, raids, world bosses and their loot in the ingame Dungeon Journal (default hotkey <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>).

Answer (score 0):

In Warlords of Draenor, we were introduced with a new raid difficulty system.  This progressive based system is divided into 4 separate categories which are:

- LFR
- Normal
- Heroic
- Mythic

Mythic is where you end game gear is obtained.  Current End game is High Maul, but is not a final end game result as normally Blizzard delivers 2 additional content patches within a years time of the initial release of the Expansion.